# How to scan previous list values in order to add a new composite list value?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list

My problem is a bit hard to explain in words so please bear with me while I try my best. I have an array ‘a’ and I’m trying to write a piece of code which will tell when each component is working and if multiple components have failed at once. You can see when a component has failed if it says C1NW as this stands for ‘Component 1 Not Working’ or when a component is working it will say C2W which stands for ‘Component 2 Working’. As you can see from the list 'a' they are already sorted in time order so at time 1067 component 2 isn’t working.

```
a = [ [1067.8420440505633, 'C2NW'], [1287.3506292298346, 'C1NW'], [1363.9930359848377, 'C2W'], [1483.1371597306722, 'C1W'], [1767.6648314715849, 'C2NW']
```

Ideally, I would like a ‘Time Line’ array with a ‘Component Working or Not’ array to compare with. Essentially, I would like an array that looks like this:

```
TimeLine = [1067.8420440505633, 1287.3506292298346, 1363.9930359848377, 1483.1371597306722, 1767.6648314715849]
WorkingOrNot = [ C2NW, C1NWC2NW, C1NWC2W, C1WC2W, C1WC2NW]
```

The WorkingOrNot array comes from each point so looking at ‘list 2 of a’ you’ll notice that C1 is not working but as C2 still isn’t working yet (List 1 of a shows that C2 isn’t working and it doesn’t start working until list 3 of a) therefore the output should be C1NWC2NW as both components aren’t working at this time.
 I know I can get the ‘Time Line’ array with:

```
TimeLine = [item[0] for item in a]
```

However, I am not sure how to get the other array as this would mean scanning behind the list to check if a certain component was working or not. 
I’m hoping that I have explained this well enough if not please comment if you would like me to reword as I really struggled to explain this.

Thanks in advance,
Ben

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
import re

a = [ [1067.8420440505633, 'C2NW'], [1287.3506292298346, 'C1NW'], [1363.9930359848377, 'C2W'], [1483.1371597306722, 'C1W'], [1767.6648314715849, 'C2NW'] ]

Timeline, statuses = zip(*a)

WorkingOrNot = []
current_statuses = {}

# Regex pattern to extract component and working/not working status
pattern = re.compile(r'(C\d+)(\w+)')

for status in statuses:
    match = pattern.search(status)
    # Set the key corresponding to component to the status (W or NW)
    current_statuses[match[1]] = match[2]
    WorkingOrNot.append(''.join(map(''.join, sorted(current_statuses.items(), key=lambda kv: int(kv[0][1:])))))

print(WorkingOrNot)
# ['C2NW', 'C1NWC2NW', 'C1NWC2W', 'C1WC2W', 'C1WC2NW']
```

The code is fairly self-explanatory. The only confusing parts may be

```
Timeline, statuses = zip(*a)
```

which is equivalent to

```
TimeLine = [item[0] for item in a]
statuses = [item[1] for item in a]
```

And this line:

```
WorkingOrNot.append(''.join(map(''.join, sorted(current_statuses.items(), key=lambda kv: int(kv[0][1:])))))
```

This does nothing other than format the output into the desired format form its dictionary form. Sorting the dictionary my component ID, join the key (component) and value (`'W'` or `'NW'`), then join all of that.

Comment: That last line is really a pain to look at, but still +1, you were faster than me

Answer (score 1):

You only need to maintain a current state for both components as you move forward through the timeline.

```
from functools import reduce

timeLine     = []
workingOrNot = []

states     = [ (item[0],item[1][:2],item[1][2:]) for item in a ]
combined = dict()
for time,component,state in states:
    combined[component] = state
    timeLine.append(time)
    components = "".join(sorted("".join(s) for s in combined.items()))
    workingOrNot.append(components)
```

*note that this would be simpler if your component identifiers and working states were separate fields (which is essentially what I had to do before processing the data)*